# Knight's Tour on a 7x7 Board starting from D5

Tags: visual, checkerboard, knight-moves

[image]

Average Knight's Tour puzzle but this time on a 7x7 and starting from D5

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is my answer:

> It's not possible, because if you color the board and $A1$ be black, there will be $25$ black cells and $24$ white cells.
>
>  As we start from the white cell of $D5$, and each move of the knight will alter the color, then it's impossible to reach all black cells.